# Create button using OpenGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Can anyone give me an simple example of creating a button using OpenGL in Android?

I googled but did not find any suitable link.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "button" in OpenGL... There's triangles.
Maybe you want to texture a quad, but you'll need to give us a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are frameworks such as Cocos2d you may use. If you want to create it from scratch it's really just a textured rectangle as MadcoreTom commented, you do need to still write all the handling with touches and probably some states. Another problem is putting on some text from string. But again in most cases it's just a textured rectangle and an if statement...